# Flutter: Reload the SplashScreen on button click

Tags: flutter, dart

My Flutter app use the [splashscreen](https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen) package. The SplashScreen stay in place as long as my data has not been fetched, and if there is a problem (e.g. no internet connection), I display a button to retry.

With this code, I tought that when the user tap the button, my SplashScreen will re-appear and my app will try to fetch the datas again, but it's not the case.

If I retry without internet connection, I only got the snackbar which says me there is no connection, no splashscreen.

And if I retry with an internet connection, my data are loaded, but nothing happen, the SplashScreen doesn't appear and my home page is not loaded. I think I do something wrong but I don't know what.

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(debug: false);

  runApp(GetMaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  MainSingleton mainSingleton = MainSingleton();
  bool authorsLoaded = false;
  bool tagsLoaded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SplashScreen(
        routeName: "/",
        navigateAfterFuture: loadFromFuture(),
        title: new Text('MyApp'),
        image: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png')),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        photoSize: 100.0,
        loaderColor: Colors.green);
  }

  Future<Widget> loadFromFuture() async {
    final MainSingleton mainSingleton = MainSingleton();
    this.authorsLoaded = await loadAuthors(mainSingleton);
    this.tagsLoaded = await loadTags(mainSingleton);
    return buildHomePage();
  }

  Widget buildHomePage() {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: (this.authorsLoaded && this.tagsLoaded) ? HomePage() : buildRetryPage(),
    );
  }

  Widget buildRetryPage() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("MyApp")),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Impossible to fetch datas'),
            GFButton(
                text: "Retry",
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    // The setState should rebuilt the SplashScreen and call my loading functions, right ?
                    // Then, if everything is ok, launch the HomePage(), right ?
                  });
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Obviously, if I launch the app for the first time with an internet connection, everything is fine, my splashscreen is displayed and my home page also.

If someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the the same page again

```
var route = MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=> MyApp());
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(route);
```

pushReplacement replaces the current page with a new one, it means that the old page won't stay in the memory stack.